# To solve an ode system with pulses

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve an ode system with pulses, for example

```
x'[t] == b*(1 - x[t]) - a*x[t]*y[t], 
y'[t] == a*x[t]*y[t] - d*y[t] 
in {t,0,1}
```

and then at the end of each period, a pulse occurs, for example, in the next period in {t,1,2},

```
x[0]=x[1],y[0]=y[1]*(1+x[1]),...,
```

and so on. I made the following code but it seems not to work.

```
IDESolver[{x0_, y0_}, {a_, d_, b_, T_}, 
  MaxPeriod_] := Module[{sol, resulttable},
  resulttable = {};
  Do[
    sol = 
     NDSolve[{x'[t] == b*(1 - x[t]) - a*x[t]*y[t], 
       y'[t] == a*x[t]*y[t] - d*y[t], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];
    AppendTo[resulttable, sol];
    x[0] = Evaluate[x[T] /. sol];
    y[0] = Evaluate[(y[T]*(1+x[T])) /. sol] ;, {i, 1, MaxPeriod}
    ]
   resulttable
  ]

IDESolver[{0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 1}, 10]
```

Can anybody help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It seems not to work..." What about it doesn't work? Does it spit out errors? Does it spit out a wrong solution (if so, what is the solution you expect and how does it differ from the wrong solution)? Have you narrowed down where the problem is? Etc.

Comment: It does not work and gives errors such as "$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a small change and i think it is now working.

```
   IDESolver[{x0_, y0_}, {a_, d_, b_, T_}, MaxPeriod_] := 
      Block[{X0 = x0, Y0 = y0, sol, resulttable}, resulttable = {};
       Do[
        sol = 
         NDSolve[{x'[t] == b*(1 - x[t]) - a*x[t]*y[t], 
           y'[t] == a*x[t]*y[t] - d*y[t], x[0] == X0, y[0] == Y0}, {x, 
           y}, {t, 0, T}];
        AppendTo[resulttable, sol];

        X0 = Evaluate[x[T] /. sol];
        Y0 = Evaluate[(y[T]*(1 + x[T])) /. sol];, {i, 1, MaxPeriod}] ;
       Flatten[resulttable]
       ];
    listsols = IDESolver[{0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 1}, 10];
    Table[Plot[listsols[[i]][[2]][x], {x, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 
      Length[listsols]}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It still gives errors such as "$RecursionLimit::reclim: ""Recursion depth of 256 exceeded." PS. I am using Mathematica 7 on Mac.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10 on Windows 8 and its is working fine...

Comment: I restart the Kernel and it is working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 7):

In the case where you actually want a continuous time variable, the function `WhenEvent` will be extremely useful. I've modified your code to:

```
Clear[IDESolver, x, y, sol]
IDESolver[{x0_, y0_}, {a_, d_, b_, period_}, tMax_] :=
  NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == b*(1 - x[t]) - a*x[t]*y[t]
    , y'[t] == a*x[t]*y[t] - d*y[t]
    , x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0
    , WhenEvent[Mod[t, period] == 0, y[t] -> y[t] (1 + x[t])]
   }
   , {x, y}
   , {t, 0, tMax}]
```

Then,

```
sol = First@IDESolver[{0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.2}, 1, 10];
Plot[Evaluate[# /. sol], {t, 0, 10}] & /@ {x[t], y[t]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Comment: @SteveX. You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer that you find most helpful by clicking the grey checkmark next to that answer!